# How to call a Java file from a dropdown menu item in php when button clicks

Tags: java, php

I have created a dropdown menu in Php with submenu items. How to call a Java file when one menuitem clicks?. Also I need to return my dropdown menu when I exiit from java jframe form in case I am not focusing to another java form module.Basically I am looking for a command equivalent to Host command in oracle. I want to run a compiled java file without using script in php. Is it possible to refer file name in  php href?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Please also make clear, whether you actually mean Java here - or JavaScript (two completely different things.) And what “calling a Java file” (or JavaScript) would even be supposed to mean in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

With the information did you provide, for call a function js when user click on menu this is an example:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Unless it's a typo OP wants to call a Java file, not Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to call the Java file directly without using function? My java file contains Class, methods and objects.